# high and low pass filter provide the same result using butter in R

Tags: r, filter, butterworth

I have a GSR signal which has relevant data around the 2Hz and lower frequencies and some noise above that which you can see in a spectral plot. However, when I try the butter filter options from the signal library in R, I get the same result out from both the high and low pass tags. It appears to be acting like a high pass either way. Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

```
bfhigh <- butter(order, fc/(fs/2), type = "high")
GSRNoise <- filter(bfhigh, GSRts)
bflow <- butter(order, fc/(fs/2), type = "low")
GSRSig <- filter(bfhigh, GSRts)
plot(GSRSig)
plot(GSRNoise)
```

Comment: You're applying the highpass filter instead of the lowpass filter: `GSRSig <- filter(bfhigh, GSRts)`

Comment: AHHHH Thank you for spotting this for me!